# Linear vs. Quadratic Programming: Complexity and Practical Efficiency

Tags: svm, linear-programming

Are quadratic programs harder than linear programs to solve (or vice-versa?)  How much harder?

I'm interested both in theoretical results and what sort of differences there tend to be in practice.

Answer (score 3):

In practice, convex quadratic programming problems (with linear equality and inequality constraints) are not much harder than similarly sized LP's to solve.  There are specialized algorithms for convex QP or you can convert the problem into a second order cone programming problem.  These are solvable in polynomial time.

However, when the problems become non-convex, it becomes much harder (in terms of computational complexity NP-Hard) to solve these problems.  Even so, non-convex QP with linear constraints is one of the easier non-convex optimization problems to solve to optimality using (for example) branch and bound methods.